# How can I style this HTML5 navigation bar?

Tags: css, html

This is my code for navigation:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <nav class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">COMPANY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MARKETS/SOLUTIONS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS/SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BUSINESSES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">INVESTORS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            </header>
            </div>
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:12px;
}
.wrapper{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
nav ul{
    background-color: red;

}
nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px;

}
nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
nav ul li:first-child:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color:none;
}
nav ul li:hover{
    background-color:#000;
}
```

[Demo on JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubz7Lcft/6/)

If I put `width:960px;` for the wrapper, it will cut the margin on both sides. I need to avoid using `text-align:center;` for `nav ul` because of what happens when the window is resized. When the window is shrunk, lists should be center aligned; in window of normal size, lists should be displayed in the left side of the navigation bar.

Comment: Hey you have written <div class="wrpper">... make it as <div class="wrapper">... Spell it properly

Comment: And what exactly you looking for ? responsive menu?

Comment: No sir, when shrink the window, lists are aligned in center. and when in normal window, lists are displayed in left side of navigation.

Comment: Actually when you look at your JSFiddle the navigation links are always aligned to the left regardless of whether the window is large or small, at least in Chrome. Sasi can you be more specific on what you want the final menu to do?

Comment: @crazymatt: when shrink the window (at 25%), it shows like http://imgur.com/RMn9ITt.. so i need lists are only aligned in center when shrink the window.. did you get my question?

Comment: @sasi. I've tried to edit your question to (a) include all relevant code, and (b) improve clarity. I'm having difficulty understanding you, though, and it looks like everyone else here is also struggling. Could you perhaps give more than one screenshot, showing what you want for small and large screen sizes?

Answer (score 1):

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ubz7Lcft/11/) or [SHOW](http://jsfiddle.net/ubz7Lcft/11/show/) [EDITED]

You could use CSS3 `@media` queries for small screen sizes.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">COMPANY</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">MARKETS/SOLUTIONS</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS/SERVICES</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">BUSINESSES</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">INVESTORS</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:12px;
}
.wrapper {
    max-width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
    background-color: red;
}
nav ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px;
}
nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
nav ul li:first-child:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color:none;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background-color:#000;
}
@media (max-width: 960px) {
    nav {
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. but stil i didn't get what i want

Comment: ...and what you want??? weren't you asking for center the navigation when screen size is small, your question is kinda unclear.....

Comment: its written as '<div class="wrpper">' but you guys applying style for '.wrapper'... Spelling mistake... or else remove above the style from '.wrapper' because its not applied..

Comment: @AdarshGowdaKR my bad, I didn't notice it. lol...

Comment: Check is out http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/ubz7Lcft/2/

Comment: @sasi please check - http://jsfiddle.net/ubz7Lcft/11/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ubz7Lcft/11/show/

Comment: I've updated my answer as well...

Comment: @MaryMelody: i didn't like this.. please understand my question.

Comment: Mary Melody, the question is very very unclear. In that situation, *vote to close as unclear* and *request clarification in comments*. Encourage OP to edit question to improve clarity. If the OP prefers to engage in comments, and is struggling with language issues, you edit the question for them. The thing you *don't* do is answer, until you've established what the question actually is.

Comment: @TRiG Thanks! but I've already answered the question and I don't have enough reputation to vote close as unclear...

Answer (score 0):

First correct the spelling of `wrapper` and then set its width to 80%.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <nav class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">COMPANY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MARKETS/SOLUTIONS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS/SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BUSINESSES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">INVESTORS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            </header>
            </div>
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:12px;
}
.wrapper{
    width:80%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
nav ul{
    background-color: red;

}
nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px;

}
nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
nav ul li:first-child:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color:none;
}
nav ul li:hover{
    background-color:#000;
}
```

[Demo on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/ubz7Lcft/2/)

Comment: not like that,when shrink the window (at 25%), it shows like imgur.com/RMn9ITt .. so i need lists are only aligned in center when shrink the window.. did you get my question?

Comment: ok for that you have to apply text-center property for nav ul ... check out this link... http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/ubz7Lcft/5/

Comment: but in normal window, i need to show nav ul is not in center.

Comment: @sasi JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ubz7Lcft/8/show/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ubz7Lcft/8/

Comment: still no one get my question. i need like this when normal window: http://imgur.com/dUCP3VM , and i need like this when shrink the window http://imgur.com/lhlY1XC

Comment: I got it at last here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/ubz7Lcft/12/

Comment: see not like this .. please understand my question. from this http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/ubz7Lcft/2/ correct.. but when shrink the window, lists only need to center.

Comment: The for that just include this code at the bottom @media(max-width:992px){
    nav ul{
        text-align:center;
    
}
}

Comment: still no one get my question. i need like this when normal window: imgur.com/dUCP3VM  , and i need like this when shrink(ctrl->-) the window imgur.com/lhlY1XC

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you looking for http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/ubz7Lcft/9/

Style your **CSS** using media quires

Changes made

```
.wrapper{
    width:100%; /*takes full width*/
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

nav ul{
    background-color: red;
    text-align:left; /* for normal view */
    padding-left:0

}

@media(max-width:992px){
    nav ul{
        text-align:center /* for resize */
}
}
```

Comment: from your answer, when shrink the window, it is not show in center.

Answer (score 0):

Changed made in **CSS**

```
nav {
    background-color: red; /*apply color for nav instead of ul */
}
nav ul{

    text-align:left;
    padding-left:0

}
@media(max-width:992px){
    nav ul{
        text-align:center;
    width:80%; /*reduce the list width */
    margin:0 auto; /* to make it align center */
}
}
```